# Mobile careers site missing Joel test colour

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, mobile-web, joel-test

[image]

The Joel test scores should be in green boxes. If no-green-boxes is intended, then the key at the bottom of the page saying they're in green boxes should be removed.

Latest iOS & Safari.

Comment: White is the new green...

Comment: Does that say *penis* modeling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The green boxes around Joel test scores had disappeared... but now they're back!

Edit: Oh but wait, this is not where the box should be, that is fixed as well.

[image]

Thank you for your report!